# Python: If statement "If not none" handling

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, error-handling, nonetype

I am using Python's regex with an if-statement: if the match is `None`, then it should go to the `else` clause. But it shows this error:

> `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

The script is:

```
import string
chars = re.escape(string.punctuation)
sub='FW: Re: 29699' 
if re.search("^FW: (\w{10})",sub).group(1) is not None :
    d=re.search("^FW: (\w{10})",sub).group(1)
else:
    a=re.sub(r'['+chars+']', ' ',sub)
    d='_'.join(a.split())
```

Every help is great help!

Comment: You've written `is not None` rather than `is None`, which seems to be what you need.

Comment: First error is import re

Comment: Even then it's not working

Comment: You cannot group none objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is this: if your search doesn't find anything, it will return `None`. You can't do `None.group(1)`, which is what your code amounts to. Instead, check whether the *search result* is `None`—not the search result's first group.

```
import re
import string

chars = re.escape(string.punctuation)
sub='FW: Re: 29699' 
search_result = re.search(r"^FW: (\w{10})", sub)

if search_result is not None:
    d = search_result.group(1)
else:
    a = re.sub(r'['+chars+']', ' ', sub)
    d = '_'.join(a.split())

print(d)
# FW_RE_29699
```

Comment: that's so logical, Thanks!